# Resize div onclick of another div, transition effect

Tags: jquery, html, xhtml, css

Hey guys. Basically I have 2 divs. When I click .menu (The grey bar), .sort (The orange bar) resizes in height. I've done this using jQuery. The problem is, it does it without any nice transitions. It doesn't slide, it doesn't fade..nothing. It just pops down.

Here's a JSFiddle of what I mean. http://jsfiddle.net/KhcvR/

Can someone possibly help me so that it slides down rather than pops? My jQuery knowledge is super limited. Cheers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your demo was using mootools even though your question was tagged jquery. I cleaned up the demo a bit.

Demo here : http://jsfiddle.net/jomanlk/KhcvR/1/

Code here

```
$(".menu").click(function() {
    $(".sort").animate({"height" : "350"}, 500);
 });
```

Comment: Default is already 500. no need to specify that unless you want a speed other then 500.

Comment: @Hussein  I thought it was 400. I actually put it in there so OP can change the value to their needs

Comment: @johnP i did not downvote you. You're actually right. Looking at the jQuery source, 400 is the default.

Comment: @johnp I'll give you a +1 to get rid of the negative.

Comment: @Hussein ah no worries then. Random downvote I guess. I can't really see why this is downvote worthy :S Thanks for the +1 :)

Answer (score 3):

Click once to slide Down and again to slide back up

```
$(".menu").toggle(function() {
    $(".sort").animate({
        height: 350
    });
}, function() {
    $(".sort").animate({
        height: 25
    });
});
```

### Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/KhcvR/2/

Answer (score 2):

```
$(".menu").click(function() {
    $(".sort").animate({ height : 350 });
 });
```

There's quite a bit of other options with slide and also additional parameters you can set on animate to change the speed and fire a callback function when it's complete. Take a look at [animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) as it's super cool unless you're changing font contents (then it gets a little messy sometimes).